# How to take a embedded object and make it the main object in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a model that tracks which user has followed which author. In an endpoint I need to serve the array of followers of an author. For that I have made a query to the database passing `author` for filtering and populated the `follower` field. the data looks something like this:

```
[
    {
      "follower": {
        "_id": ""
        "name": "",
        "profilePicture": "",
        "phone": "",
        "email": ""
      },
      "author": "6137378438a6eb01a6a669ab",
      "_id": "6131fb2e486dd00c88c99ed5"
    },
    {
      "follower": {
        "_id": ""
        "name": "",
        "profilePicture": "",
        "phone": "",
        "email": ""
      },
      "author": "6137378438a6eb01a6a669ab",
      "_id": "6131fb2e486dd00c88c99ed5"
    }
  ]
```

But the data I want is only of the followers. How can I take the follower's object and make it the make object such that the above result will be array of followers object.

Answer (score 0):

Use [project](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) and [map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#behavior)

```
await Model.find({}, { follower: 1 }).map(f => f.follower);
```